# If else not working..

Tags: wordpress

I want to show a template content if ad not available

i use this code but

both ad & template content are showing

```
<?php
    if(dt_show_ads('position=Header&before=<div>&after=</div>'))
    {
?>
    <!-- Some content here -->
<?php
    }
    else
    {
        include TEMPLATEPATH.'/templates/newsleft_col.tpl.php';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dt_show_ads('position=Header&before=<div>&after=</div>')` seems to not return any value. This evaluates to `false` in PHP.

What `dt_show_ads()` does, though, is to insert ad html (if there is any).

Therefor, no matter if there are ads or not, your `else` part is always executed.

A quick google query didn't turn up any sensible documentation on dt_show_ads for me, you might wanna try this though:

```
if (strlen($ads = dt_show_ads('position=Header&before=<div>&after=</div>&echo=false')) !== 0)
{
    echo $ads;
    // whatever other content you want to show
}
else
{
    include TEMPLATEPATH.'/templates/newsleft_col.tpl.php';
}
```

**Edit:**

Since, per your comment, `dt_show_ads()` doesn't support the WP-semi-standard `echo` argument, you'll need to buffer its output to be able to check it:

```
ob_start();
dt_show_ads('position=Header&before=<div>&after=</div>');
$ads = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

if (strlen($ads) !== 0)
{
    echo $ads;
    // whatever other content you want to show
}
else
{
    include TEMPLATEPATH.'/templates/newsleft_col.tpl.php';
}
```

Comment: It seems like `dt_show_ads()` doesn't support the `echo` argument then. Gimme a sec, I'll post a hackish update in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

There is no posibility to get both states of the IF statement. There is something wrong with your code. You may have not show up here all of your code correctly ?

---

### Answer #2

The function that you check:

```
if(dt_show_ads('position=Header&before=<div>&after=</div>'))
{
}
else
{
}
```

It can print out the appropriate HTML and at the end return a false in example. In that case you get false for the first IF statement and the because of the false you get the else part.

To be sure what is the result of the dt_show_ads(); do that:

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r(dt_show_ads('position=Header&before=<div>&after=</div>'), true) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php 
if (!dt_show_ads('position=Header&before=<div>&after=</div>')) {
include TEMPLATEPATH.'/templates/newsleft_col.tpl.php';}
?>
```